# mysql define variable across all sessions

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a table with a few variables (let's say tbl_param). I have to query tbl_param everytime I need to use one of them. I have a case where I need to use those variables inside triggers, so I have to query tbl_param each time those triggers are executed. But what if I am going to use the same variable for every user that connects to the db? It would be logical to set them only once, since it would not change often (only when the variable in question gets updated in tbl_param). I know I can set session variables, but it would not solve the problem as they would be acessible only for the duration of one connection. So when a new connection is made, I would need to query tbl_param again. Can I define, for instance, a new system variable that gets loaded when the server boots up and and that I could update it as tbl_param gets updated? Or is there another alternative?

Comment: You can use an Environment variable

Comment: that is clever, I'll look into that.

Comment: well, i couldn't find a way to read and set environment variables from within the queries, so i cannot use them.

Answer (score 0):

There are system that can be defined in mysql.cnf (or mysql.ini) file; but this will require you to had file permissions on that file. On my local server (Ubuntu 20.04.2) it is in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf. but this would not work on remote server; because we didn't have access to system files (etc).

I had found an alternative to this that would serve the purpose what you had in mind. SET a session variable (wait for it; i know session variables disappears in other sessions); but initialize it value to some value from a table. e.g initialize your session variable always on startup from a table (and update accordingly to table as required).

---

### In case of using a PHP (MIS) to disable mysql triggers

To disable a trigger on some table for some specific record(s). instead of deleting the triggers and inserting the records and then recreating those triggers. just rewrite the trigger with a minor change. it would disable based on this session variable.

Then your MIS would always initialize a session variable to some value fetched from table. and based on this value skip or execute triggers.